# how to find resolution with React native

Tags: react-native

I have installed react-native-blur.
but I met error.
This is error message.

> react-native-blur\android\src\main\java\com\cmcewen\blurview\BlurringView.java:
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API. Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation
>   for details.

Comment: What fixes have you already attempted?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add this in `android/build.gradle` (not in the app folder)

```js
allprojects {
    ...

    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }   
}
```